# How do I paraphrase "distribute as evenly as possible"?

Tags: paraphrasing

For the phrase "distribute as evenly as possible", could we use a simpler one—something like "distribute evenly possible" or  "distribute possibly evenly". I know these are wrong, but I can't figure out the right one.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I would think that "distribute evenly" already sort-of could mean "distribute approximately equally". You could also consider "distribute optimally" or even "distribute fairly" (depending on the context).

Comment: ... distribute uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

**Distribute as evenly as possible** means "distribute as evenly as (is) possible", in other words, as evenly as one can.   It is a comparative construction.  The commanded distribution is to be compared with a distribution evincing the greatest evenness that can be.

"evenly possible"  makes no sense as possibility is neither even nor uneven, regular or irregular.

Compare:

> Jump as far as possible.
>
> Jump far possible <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Comment: This would benefit from a conclusion like "so there is no way to remove words from "as evenly as possible" without the meaning changing or the becoming meaningless."

Answer (score 0):

In America people might say “let’s divy up the stuff” or depending on how many people are involved they might say “let’s split this stuff 2/3/4/etc ways”

Comment: Does "divy up" always suggest an even split (without further qualification)?